# Help me understand on what to do after I square a pi in a trig integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have a function  $y = xsin(x^2)$

I need to determine the area bounded by the curve and the x-axis as shown in this diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6SIZ.jpg

So my working out is as follows:

$\int sin(x^2) dx$

let $u = x^2$

$du/dx = 2x$

$du/2 = x dx$

$\int \frac{1}{2} sin(x^2) du$

$ = -\frac{1}{2} cos(u) + C $

$ = -\frac{1}{2} cos(x^2) + C $

This is the indefinite integral, but we want to find the total area bounded by the curve and x-axis.

According to the graph, the first part area A area of is from 0 to π.

And the part B area is from π to 2π.

Total area = Area A + Area B

$ A = -\frac{1}{2} [cos(x^2) ]_0^π$

$ = -\frac{1}{2} [cos(π^2) - cos(0^2) ]$

$ = -\frac{1}{2} [cos(π^2) - 1 ] $

$ B = -\frac{1}{2} [cos(x^2)]_π^{2π} $

$ = -\frac{1}{2} [cos({2π}^2) - cos({π}^2)] $

What do I do after this step?

I know Total Area = A + B

But I'm not too sure whether you can square a π?

I entered Area A's equation into my calculator but I get 0.007... which is obviously incorrect. Can someone explain how to input this to get the correct approx in a scientific calc?

Comment: May be a typing error? I entered (1-cos(pi^2))/2 and Google gave me 0.95134268096 + Of course you may square any number (including $\pi$).

Comment: In your $B$, it should be $(2\pi)^2$ instead of $2\pi^2.$ But anyway, your bounds for $A$ and $B$ should not be $\pi$ and $2\pi$ but their square roots.

Comment: The first intersection should be $x = \sqrt{\pi}$ and the second $x = \sqrt{2\pi}$ since you have $\sin(\color{red}{x^{2}})$

Comment: You will find $B<0.$ I think you want to consider the corresponding area to be $|B|.$

Comment: @Manifoldski hey, how did you work out the intercepts? Is that just making y = 0 and solving for y = sin(x^2)?

Comment: Ah, yes, I made a typo - B should be (2*pi)^2

Comment: @Strider I did essentially like Joey Shi did in their answer. I looked at the picture and thought "Oh when would $\sin(t) =0$, well $t = \pi$ or $t = 2\pi$ fits nicely with the picture. But wait, I have $x^{2}$, so it should be $x^{2} = \pi$ or $x^{2} = 2\pi$" and then I took the positive root since we are to the right of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your issue about squaring $\pi$.
The square of any real number will be another real number.

Let $f(x) = x\sin(x^2)$. $f(x) = x\sin(x^2) = 0$ if and only if $x^2 = \pi n$ for any integer $n$. So, $A$ can be computed from taking the integral of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $\sqrt{\pi}$ and $B$ is the integral from $\sqrt{\pi}$ to $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

I will assume you don't want to calculate the *signed area* for this (this is $0$). Then,
\begin{align}
A &= \left|\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}} x\sin(x^2) dx \right| \\
&= \int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{1}{2}\sin(x^2) d(x^2) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\cos(x^2) \big|_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}} \\
&= 1 \\
B &= \left|\int_{\sqrt{\pi}}^{\sqrt{2\pi}} x\sin(x^2) dx \right| \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cos(x^2) \big|_{\sqrt{\pi}}^{\sqrt{2\pi}} \\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Thus, $A + B = 2$ is the unsigned area bounded between the function and the $x$-axis.

Comment: @aschepler $\pi$ is not an $x$-intercept of $f(x) = x\sin(x^2)$. If you just evaluated the function at $x = \pi$, you get $f(\pi) = \pi\sin(\pi^2) = −1.3518\ldots \neq 0$.